# parsing invalid JSON swift 5

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, codable

I have an invalid json comping from external api:

```
{
    status: 'ok',
    pills: [{
            id: 1,
            name: "Мезим форте",
            img: "https://cloud.fdoctor.ru/test_task/static/mezim.jpg",
            desription: "Перед завтраком",
            dose: "По таблетке"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "Bioderma",
            img: "https://cloud.fdoctor.ru/test_task/static/bioderma.jpg",
            desription: "Во время еды"
            dose: "По 3 глотка"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            name: "Гексорал, Аэрозоль"
            img: "https://cloud.fdoctor.ru/test_task/static/gecsoral.jpg",
            desription: "При острых болях"
            dose: "По 3 пшика"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            name: "Тантум Верде, спрей"
            img: "https://cloud.fdoctor.ru/test_task/static/tantum.jpg",
            desription: "Каждые 4 часа в течении 7 дней"
            dose: "По таблетке"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to parse it with codable protocol?

Fixing it on API is not an option.

Comment: No, there is none, `Codable` expects valid JSON. You could add the missing double quotes with regex

Comment: I guess if someone was really desperate to parse this, could try to preprocess (by using regex or any similar means) and hope to make it a valid json...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following reg ex replacements to clean the string and make it json compliant

```
//Surround keys with quotes
let firstStep = input.replacingOccurrences(of: #"\s(\w+):{1}"#, 
                                           with: #""$1":"#, 
                                           options: .regularExpression)
//Fix status value
let json = firstStep.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "\"")
```